# Twig runs in 'if variable is defined', even when variable is defined

Tags: twig

I want to include a template, when a variable is set. When the variable isn't set, the template must not be included.

```
{% if data is defined %}
    {% block content %}
        {% include 'data.html.twig' with  { 'data' : data} %} {# Line 14 #}
    {% endblock %}  
{% endif %}
```

But this check doesn't work. When `data` isn't defined an error occures:

```
 Twig_Error_Runtime: Variable "data" does not exist in "text.html.twig" at line 14
```

But Twig has to skip that line when `data` is defined. Who can explain this behaviour, en more importan: How can I solve this?

Comment: This is highly unusual. I just copied your sample and created a test, I don't have this issue, even with strict mode enabled. Might be a bug. Do you know which version of Twig you are using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to my roommate, I found the solution. The `if` has to be in the `block`. I still don't know why this is required.

```
 {% block content %}
    {% if data is defined %}
        {% include 'data.html.twig' with  { 'data' : data} %} {# Line 14 #}
   {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: good to know, still that is weird, would be inconvenient if I wanted to replace the content block or have the default but I guess you could use `{% else %}{{ parent() }}`

Comment: Thanks for this -- I just ran into this weird issue where a base template of my views would need to override certain sections of the extended view and Twig would simply ignore obvious conditions until I found this.  There is no explanation in Twig documentation that they need to be in blocks to work as expected.